# Enlarge image when hovering over parent element

Tags: css

Like many others I wanted to show an enlarged image when hovering over a thumbnail.  I used a hover selector to enlarge the image which worked fine.

Instead of having the image shrink when I moved off the image,  I wanted the image to shrink when I moved off area that was occupied by the original thumbnail which was 100px X 100px.

I put a div around it, sized it and put the :hover on it rather then the image.  I thought because the enlarged image was positioned absolute it wouldn't enlarge the div.

The image still enlarges but it does not shrink unless the cursor moves off the enlarged image.

```
div.hov:hover >.thumbnail {
  position:fixed;
  top:100px;
  left:50px;
  width:800px;
  height:auto;
  display:block;
  z-index:999;
}

div.hov{
  width:101px;
  height:101px;
  float:left;
  overflow:visible;
  margin: 10px; 
}   

<p>
  <div class="hov"><img src="./gm1.png" class="thumbnail" height="100" width="100" /></div>
  <div class="hov"><img src="./gm2.png" class="thumbnail" height="100" width="100" /></div>
</p>
```

Is there any way to achieve this?  [The hosted version is here.](http://routedecomp.sawicki.org/help.html#acc3)

Comment: achieve what? your code works http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/6va9eoch/

Comment: in my helpfile at http://routedecomp.sawicki.org/help.html#acc3  the images stay enlarged until I move off the entire enlarged image.  I would like to have them shrink when I move off the original 100x100 area.  

Your demo seems to do this as long as I stay on the original thumbnail area.  If I manage to get the cursor over the enlarged image,  then it too doesn't shrink until I move off the enlarged image.  Still the way you've placed things gets a lot closer to what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

one way to do this is to show a new modal div on top of the original image. that way your original div doesn't enlarge. however, you'll need to use some javascript or jQuery

heres a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/k3oq1899/1/

don't mind the code, I put it together very quickly for you, but you can clean it up a bit.

html

```
<div class='image'>
    <img src='http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png'/>
</div>

<div id='modal'></div>
```

css

```
.image {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
#modal {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

jquery

```
$(function() {
    var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };
    $(document).mousemove(function (event) {
        currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
        currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
        if($('#modal').css('display') != 'none') {
            $('#modal').css({
                top: currentMousePos.y,
                left: currentMousePos.x + 12
            });
        }
    });
    $('.image').on('mouseover', function() {
        var image = $(this).find('img');
        var modal = $('#modal');
        $(modal).html(image.clone());
        $(modal).css({
            top: currentMousePos.y,
            left: currentMousePos.x + 12
        });
        $(modal).show();

    });
    $('.image').on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(modal).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of enlarging the image, think of actually creating two images, one big and one small one. Once you hover over the small one, you can make the big image visible or invisible when moving out of it.
use absolute positions, display:block and display:none and check if the z-index is right.

But is this really necessary?
The hovering does not seem convenient to me....

Answer (score 0):

You can put an invisible DIV with same dimensions over the thumbnail, put it on top with z-index and use it for the hover-event. But you need a few lines of javascript (with jQuery in my example).

HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437" alt="">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-image">
        <img src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/mrmen/images/5/52/Small.gif/revision/latest?cb=20100731114437" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript (jQuery)

```
$('.overlay').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).closest('.box').addClass('show-large-image');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).closest('.box').removeClass('show-large-image');
});
```

CSS

```
.box {
    padding: 200px;
}
.thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #888;
}
.overlay {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.large-image {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 500px;
}
.large-image img {
    width: 100%;
}
.box.show-large-image .large-image {
    display: block;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dx0d1ceh/